# How to store the result of a select query into a variable(IBM DB2)?

Tags: db2

I am trying to save the result of a query into a variable. I am using IBM DB2, but I can only store the result if I am declaring the variable inside a procedure.

My code is:

`DECLARE @myvar INTEGER;
SET @myvar = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM S0SCSQMS.S0SRPTCNAME);`

and I receive the following errors:
For the first line:"SQL0104N  An unexpected token "INTEGER" was found following "DECLARE @myvar ".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601"

The error code does not tell me much. I looked for it on the IBM documentation.

Looking forward for an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this (work on iseries db2 v7r1)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE myvar INTEGER ;

SET myvar = (SELECT max( id_xp_dossier) FROM cilgprod.xp_dossier);

DROP VARIABLE myvar;
```